# setPointerCapture only works whilst pointer depressed?

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to click on an element, and then have another element respond to pointer move events from all elements in the html document.  However it appears that onpointermove events are only captured when the pointer is kept depressed.  For example in the following simplified code the onpointermove handler fires when you mouse over the div, or when you click down on the div, move around the screen and then click up anywhere.  But the captured is not maintained if you release the mouse button and click up anywhere.

This behaviour kind of makes sense in case you fail to invoke `releasePointerCapture` but I can't see this mentioned in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setPointerCapture) yet and before I contemplate contributing I was wondering if anyone knew if this was documented somewhere else / correct my interpretation of it.

```js
let captured = false
function toggle_capture (e) {
  if (captured) capture_div.releasePointerCapture(e.pointerId)
  else capture_div.setPointerCapture(e.pointerId)

  captured = !captured
}

const capture_div = document.getElementById("capture_div")

capture_div.onpointerdown = toggle_capture
capture_div.onpointermove = (e) => {
    capture_div.innerText = `captured: ${captured} x: ${Math.round(e.clientX)}`
}
```

```css
div
{
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="capture_div">Mouse over, click or click and hold,
Then move pointer around the screen</div>
<div>Other divs</div>
<div>Other divs</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct.  The [MDN documentation has been updated](https://github.com/mdn/content/pull/4523#pullrequestreview-647716964) and the [documentation of the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents2/#implicit-release-of-pointer-capture) contains this information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is the 'pointer lock' api - much more flexible.  Used for games and other situations where the screen position of the mouse and its icon are irrelevant.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_Lock_API

from that page:

> Pointer lock is different from mouse capture in the following ways:
>
> - It is persistent: Pointer lock does not release the mouse until an explicit API call is made or the user uses a specific release gesture.
> - It is not limited by browser or screen boundaries.
> - It continues to send events regardless of mouse button state.
> - It hides the cursor.

Apparently, Capture is more for regular operation: you make a slider, and you ensure that the user's drag isn't interrupted if the mouse strays away from the gutter line.

People have used the term 'mouse capture' to describe this, which is now confusing given W3C documentation terminology.